# django JsonResponse from POST file upload

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

I am playing around with django's fileupload and got their documentation in the example to work. Now, I would like to modify the response by using a [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#django.http.JsonResponse) like so:

```
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            # this is default as in django 1.7 docs:
            # return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
            # this is what I want to implement
            return JsonResponse({'foo': "bar"})
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
        return render_to_response('upload.html', {'form': form})
```

Now, what I'd like is to show this `return JsonResponse({'foo': "bar"})` on my template. However, I am not sure how to `get` this variable on the JS side. For example, something like:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var data = {{ foo }};
    console.log(data);
</script>
```

.. but this does not work - I am not sure how I could get the data in JS using the `JsonResponse` object from django.

Any help with this would be great!

**MORE INFO**

Since I am using dropzone.js to process my file upload, I have the following JS code:

```
## load dropzone.js
<script type="text/javascript">
    Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
        paramName: "file_field", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
        maxFilesize: 20, // MB
        // Prevents Dropzone from uploading dropped files immediately
        autoProcessQueue : true,
        clickable : true,

  init: function() {
    this.on("success", function(file, responseText) {
      // Handle the responseText here. For example, add the text to the preview element:
      file.previewTemplate.appendChild(document.createTextNode({{django_json}}));
    });
  }

        };

    </script>
```

Comment: Is the POST request being made with ajax?

Comment: @schillingt: I do not think so (should be POST be done using ajax?) - is there a link somewhere in docs on how I should be doing this?

Comment: Well it depends on what your view is being used for. I assume it's for a web application and not a web service. In that case, if you want to return a JSON response, it'd be because you are using an ajax request. I'll post an answer with what I think you want.

Comment: Yes it is a web application. Actually, the file uploads are handled by dropzone.js and I d want `def upload_file(request)` to spit out a json  (which would give me say for example the pkid of the uploaded file) - which I can use to update my current upload page.

Comment: But if you want to update your current upload page, then *yes* you need to use Ajax. Otherwise you will get a new page.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Yes, that is correct - That is why I wanted the view to return a json response. So, I look at the situation like so: (1) The normal upload page is redered (2) the `request.POST` takes care of the file upload (client side: dropzone.js) (3) Upload completes, DB updated, and now I want to send a variable (pk_id) back to the upload template. The problem I see is that at the moment JsonResponse does not seem to send any info to the upload page.. Maybe I need some JS code to read this? I am not sure!

Comment: Then you'll need to show the JS that is doing the POST. It is that that is responsible for processing the json response.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: the problem is that I am using dropzpne.js to process my files. I have added the JS code of dropzone (initialization) and the variable {{django_json}} is what I want to get back in the template. Does this help at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JS snippet that you have posted shows where you need to handle the returned JSON. The data is *passed* to your success function as "responseText":

```
this.on("success", function(file, responseText) {
  file.previewTemplate.appendChild(responseText);
});
```

but you will probably want to use `JSON.parse` to convert it to actual JS objects.

Comment: I tried this direction as well. At the moment the responseText shows me: `[object Object]`. I tried using: file.previewTemplate.appendChild(JSON.parse(responseText)); but that yields me nothing! I will look into this now..

Comment: Spent a day doing this and now I find out that responseText is already parsed json - I just had to use `responseText.foo` and I have the variable in the template! Thanks so much Daniel - something for the day!